# Upgrade Path from OS X 10.5.7 to OS X Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: mac-osx, apple, osx-leopard

I purchased an iMac back in March 2009 and it came with OS X 10.5.5 and I have been updating it since.  I see that I can upgrade the OS to "Snow Leopard" for $29.99 but......

I would like to upgrade *up* to OS X Snow Leopard **Server**, instead of the regular OS X, and was wondering if anyone knows if this is A) such an upgrade path exists and B) what the cost would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no upgrade path from OS X to OS X server and there never has been.

You would need to purchase the full version of OS X 10.6.0 Snow Leopard Server. The cost for this would be $499 for the unlimited client version.

Comment: Thank you for that info.  I had a feeling that might be the case.

Answer (score 4):

One of the supported methods of installing Mac OS X Server on a computer that the Mac OS X Server Install DVD doesn't support (eg. computer released after the DVD was released) is to install Mac OS X Client (**of the same version**) - get it up to to date and then use the DVD to install Mac OS X Server overtop. See Apple's [kbase article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3479). Of note, this is **not** supported in Mac OS X 10.6 at the present time. (Oct. 2009)

However as Dan said there is no upgrade path for buying Snow Leopard Server. Those who purchased Leopard Server (10 user or unlimited) will still have to pay the $500 for Snow Leopard Server (which is a full install DVD - not just an upgrade DVD. The same as it is with Client)

Comment: Thank you for the details on that.  I will have to keep this in mind as I consider the option of moving to Server.